# Is entropy in quantum mechanics emergent or fundamental?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, emergent-properties

Since a quantum mechanical system, even an isolated system containing one particle, can be described by a density matrix, with entropy for the system given by $\langle S\rangle=-k \rho\ln(\rho)$, is not entropy therefore a property of the system like mass or energy?

Comment: Entropy comes from ignorance of the system. We can be ignorant for a state of one, two, ..., many particles. For example, we may not know whether a particle is in state $|1 \rangle$. We use density operator to give a statistical description, just like classical statistics, $\sum_i p_i | i \rangle \langle i| $. In this aspect, it is ***irrelevant*** to ask whether fundamental or emergent.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. If the state is described by a state matrix, I don't see how ignorance or not matters. If you know the state, you operate on the state to get the info you want. To determine the state you must make a lot of measurements (from a large ensemble of identical systems identically prepared) as you would for most any QM situation. I seems to me that the _italic_more info you obtain through measurement the greater knowledge you have about the entropy (or energy, etc) of the system. _italic_Less ignorance in this case is better as far as entropy is concened

Comment: First of all, what I concerned is a formal aspect of the state and you mentioned is about practically how to know that state. It's not necessary to require a lot of measurements. For instance (althogh it is a special case), there is an oven of heated silver atoms. If I let one emit and go through a Stern-Gerlach experiment and got down spin, I know it is |↓>, or ρ=|↓><↓|, entropy 0. If I just emit one, and do not measure the spin, I cannot write a (pure) state vector, what I can say is ρ=1/2 |↓><↓|+1/2|↑><↑|. I am rather ignorant, so entropy is greater than zero.

Comment: What you describe in this situation is therefore not a state but a statistical mix of different states. What you measure then is the state of the ensemble rather than the state of a system. I don't see anything wrong  with such a formulation if it helps you find the answers you need, but I think it is important to note there is no state of a single system per se in this case. Putting an atom into a superposition of +-1/2 would preserve the concept of system state. If S < Smax the off diagonal terms should not be 0 and these values could be determined via tests of interference effects? Not sure

Comment: I am not sure if I captured your point. Unless you are looking for subsystem, e.g. an electron in entangled state, a quantum mechanical system is always a (pure) state, but not statistical mix. A silver atom is always at $$ c_{\downarrow} |\downarrow> + c_{\uparrow}|\uparrow> $$. The mixed state is somehow a misnomer. It is not a QM state, but just don't know c↓ and c↑, so I use statistics. Like throw a dice, the result is a definite side. Entropy is defined via trace. Changing representation for a superposition will make density matrix as a single, diagonal element, without changing entropy.

Comment: I thank you for your comment. What I am curious about is how much the properties of the state matrix imply physical reality. For simplicity, the system I want to describe is one particle in a box. I can define a state using a state matrix that implies this one particle system has an entropy greater than 0. Physically, what does this mean? Does the state matrix match reality?

Comment: If the state matrix is the density matrix, if it is a mixed state for a particle in box, then it is an estimation for the possible state of the particle in box. $\rho=1/2 |1 \rangle \langle 1 | + 1/2 |2 \rangle \langle 2|$ means I guess there is 50% probability that the particle is at $| 1 \rangle$ and 50% probability  that the particle is at $| 2 \rangle$. It is, in general, impossible to match reality (experimentally indistinguisable with the true state of the system) for a single particle. It could match experiment for large number of particles,just like throw a dice.1/6 for many times.

Comment: The system you describe looks like a spin system. A particle in a box for instance might have the eigenlevels base on sin(kx). The preparation could be an arbitrary superposition and if it were pure the state matrix would have the form of rho = |psi><psi| and S would be 0. The matrix would likely contain off-diagonal terms. Changes to the eigenvalues of rho may reduce the amplitude of the off diagonal terms and or change probabilities along the diagonal resulting in S>0 in principle for one particle. Know of any experimental evidence to support or refute this?

Comment: Like spin system, a state expressed in eigenstate of $S_z$ as $|\downarrow\rangle + | \uparrow \rangle$ is $|S_x + \rangle$. The diagonalized density matrix is $|S_x + \rangle \langle S_x + |$. Since entropy is defined via trace, $-k \,\, tr \rho \ln \rho$, we can compute in any representation. The diagonalized one gives the simplest procedure and the answer is zero. It is not convenient to calculate the entropy in non-diagonal representation, since $\ln \rho$ is no longer that simple to handle.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, unlike mass/energy, the entropy is not an observable. The word "observable" may be understood both as an adjective and as a noun ("an observable"). Entropy isn't an observable because it is not given by a linear operator acting on the Hilbert space (or on the space of density matrices), 
$$ L: |\psi\rangle \to L|\psi\rangle $$
Instead, the entropy (nonlinearly) depends on $\rho$ itself i.e. on the observer's knowledge of the system. Note that $\rho$ generalizes the probability distribution on the phase space in classical physics, and the latter is clearly related to subjective ignorance. It is not an operationally measurable quantity.

The entropy, like the related notion of information, is such a universal concept applicable to any theory (classical or quantum) that it makes no sense to ask whether it is emergent. It is as ill-defined as asking whether Thursdays are green. The adjective "emergent" and its approximately opposite adjective "fundamental" may only be applied to dynamical laws of physics (laws dictating how things evolve in time) and concepts governed by these laws. The entropy also evolves with time but its evolution is just a small aspect of the evolution of more general, system-specific observables such as particles' coordinates or fields.

OK, perhaps I just de facto argued that the entropy is always "emergent" because it is calculated from some more detailed degrees of freedom. But entropy is so conceptually different from other things that may be said to be "emergent" that this label attached to entropy is useless and meaningless. Entropy is "fundamental" in the sense that it is important for the understanding of information and thermodynamics in any system; it is "emergent" because its value always depend on the state of some more detailed, typically microscopic, degrees of freedom, and the "forgetting" of the microscopic details when discussing a notion may be thought to define "emergence".

Comment: I'm interested in the concept of emergent and fundamental. Could you point me some reference about these?

Comment: Hi Lubos, Thanks for your comments. From Wiki, I read, emergence is conceived as a process whereby larger entities, patterns, and regularities arise through interactions among smaller or simpler entities that themselves do not exhibit such properties. In this case of a system of one particle in a superposition state, the state matrix says this smaller simpler system possesses the "emergent" property of entropy that many people commonly insist must come about because of large numbers of particles or "coarse graining" away info about a reversible system. Thoughts?

Comment: Dear @user53081, I don't know how this comment differs from the original question, and if I would write something, it would probably not differ from what I already wrote. Just one extra comment: a large(r) number of degrees of freedom – if not the "thermodynamic limit" (infinitely many degrees of freedom, or atoms, if you wish) – is necessary for the entropy to be any accurate. One may formally define entropy even for the elementary particles or tiny systems but its exact value will depend on conventions and subjective knowledge too much. What's important is that these errors may average out.

Comment: Thanks Lubos, I just asked a question above about whether non zero entropy as predicted by the state matrix for a system of a single particle in a box has physical validity. The state matrix predicts a system of one particle could have entropy. Is this physically possible? If not, what does the state matrix then mean?

Comment: For Pu Zhang: Here are a couple of references that might be of help:https:  //www.qut.ethz.ch/  Quantum Thermodynamics

arxiv.org › quant-p
by R Kosloff - ‎2013 - ‎Related articles
May 10, 2013 -
What is Quantum Thermodynamics?
www.ing.unibs.it/...quantumthermodynamics.../

Answer (score 1):

You have provided the [von Neumann entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) definition which is derived from its density matrix. I would consider it an intrinsic rather than fundamental property, but this is just semantics.

Some recent work by John Baez has investigated the dynamics of quantum entropy called [quantropy](http://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/quantropy/).

Comment: Thanks for this info. By fundamental I mean a property of the system, like energy or mass, that can be determined via QM operators and measurement statistics. I looked over the article you provided. It seems to indicate some knowledge of dynamics was needed. What I am saying is that state matrix can describe entropy for a simple quantum state anywhere from S=0 for a pure state to S=max (stable thermal equilibrium) for a canonical or thermal state. A more of a kinematic question. The dynamics is another big question.